# Using promise instead of events Call back

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird, eventemitter

I'm having the following code, this all code is implemented in specified function `myFunc`, I need that the all function will finish (`myFunc`) i.e. when the file was extracted successfully/or not to **return** some status (success/ error).

```
var myFunc = () => {

var DecompressZip = require('decompress-zip');
var unzipper = new DecompressZip(filename)

unzipper.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Caught an error');
});

unzipper.on('extract', function (log) {
    console.log('Finished extracting');
});

unzipper.on('progress', function (fileIndex, fileCount) {
    console.log('Extracted file ' + (fileIndex + 1) + ' of ' + fileCount);
});

unzipper.extract({
    path: 'some/path',
    filter: function (file) {
        return file.type !== "SymbolicLink";
    }
});

};
```

Since this open source is working with event this is a problem (to get return status...) my intention is to change it to promise by promisify or
like following:

```
   var myFunc = () => {
    
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var DecompressZip = require('decompress-zip');
    var unzipper = new DecompressZip(filename)
    
    unzipper.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('Caught an error');
        reject();
    });
    
    unzipper.on('extract', function (log) {
        console.log('Finished extracting');
        resolve();
    });
    
    unzipper.on('progress', function (fileIndex, fileCount) {
        console.log('Extracted file ' + (fileIndex + 1) + ' of ' + fileCount);
    });
    
    unzipper.extract({
        path: 'some/path',
        filter: function (file) {
            return file.type !== "SymbolicLink";
        }
    });
    
    };
```

**My questions are:**

1. Since I'm not too expert in JS Does it make sense to **convert the events to promise**?
2. There is other
   good solution which I can use for the use-case?

This is the OP
https://github.com/bower/decompress-zip

Comment: Yes, if you want your caller to be able to wait for the (single) `extract` event then returning a promise makes absolute sense.

Comment: You should pass the `err` into `reject()`

Comment: @Bergi I suspect OP isn't the owner of the code. That would be a problem on Code Review.

Comment: You should check out using [`jszip`](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) it will take care of reading a zip and returning a promise for you. Its also maintained.

Comment: @Bergi - thank you very much :)  ,if the error is fits my requirement I just pass it like this reject(err); but  if I need different text I use reject(new Error("new text")  is it ok?

Comment: @JennyM: Yes, that's fine as well

Comment: @Bergi - Great thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting events to promises only makes sense when you are absolutely positive that the "end" event will only fire once.

So in this case, yes, what you are suggesting for the implementation should work (assuming I understand your code correctly).

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes it makes perfect sense to convert such events to a Promise. Currently, different libraries have different ways of expressing events (events, messages, callback functions, then error callback function, exceptions, error codes, etc...). Promises will soon unify all this now they're a Javascript standard. So it a good practice to put a Promise layer around the libraries you're using and use only Promises in your code instead of the old mess.

2) Your solution looks good to me.